# Monotonicity in negation normal form

Tags: logic

I was reading [this paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/149412/MIT-LCS-TR-1010.pdf?sequence=2&isAllowed=y), and I didn't understand the phrase:

> The proof of Theorem 1 relies on the monotonicity of logical
> operations and quantifiers in negation normal form of a formula.

I wonder whether someone understands what is meant here.